# find the total hours worked on each days for calculating attendance by eliminating the invalid check and repeat check using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing fields such as `name, checkInOut Time, checkState,and Exception`.

Here I want to calculate  total hours worked on each day by avoiding the exception such as **invalid and repeat**.

The table is give below.

```
A/cNo   User    CheckInOutTime  Check State    Exception

2       2   04-01-2015 10:03                    Invalid
2       2   04-01-2015 23:19                    Invalid
2       2   04-03-2015 08:28    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-03-2015 15:40    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-05-2015 09:12                    Invalid
2       2   04-06-2015 10:08    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-06-2015 15:42    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-09-2015 17:18                    Invalid
2       2   04-10-2015 10:00    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-10-2015 18:35    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-11-2015 08:39    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-11-2015 17:45    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-13-2015 09:43    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-13-2015 15:11    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-13-2015 15:32    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-13-2015 18:06    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-14-2015 08:37    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-14-2015 14:37    OverTime Out    FOT
2       2   04-14-2015 14:58                    Repeat
2       2   04-14-2015 14:59                    Invalid
2       2   04-14-2015 15:09    OverTime In     FOT
2       2   04-14-2015 17:36    OverTime Out    FOT
```

Here FOT is a valid check, so it can be taken into account for calculating  the attendance... please help me.

Comment: please add what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used if there isn't any records where the check in and the check out isn't on the same day:

```
select a.[User], CONVERT(date,a.CheckInOutTime) [Date], sum(DATEDIFF(HOUR, a.CheckInOutTime, b.CheckInOutTime) /*Calculate the differencies in hour*/) [Hours worked on day]
from [YourTable] a
  cross apply (select top 1 * from [YourTable] b where b.Exception='FOT' and a.[User] = b.[USER] and b.[Check State]='OverTime Out' and b.CheckInOutTime>a.CheckInOutTime order by b.CheckInOutTime) b --I need the next closest CheckOutTime
where a.Exception = 'FOT' --I need just the valid records
  and a.[Check State]='OverTime In' --I need the begining of the OverTime
group by a.[User], CONVERT(date,a.CheckInOutTime) --Aggregate the calculated differencies to User, and date
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the above query.. Note that here the check In and check Out are done on the same day..